# How to read data frame in R into existing SQL table?

Tags: sql, r

Here is my code:

```
dbSendQuery(con, "create table origdata (day1 numeric, day2 numeric, day3 numeric, day4 numeric, day5 numeric, day6 numeric, day7 numeric, day8 numeric, day9 numeric, day10 numeric);")

#3.4
data=data.frame(origData)
data[is.na(data)]=0
dbWriteTable(con, "origdata", value=origData, row.names =F,append = T)
```

But I am getting the error  : Error in postgresqlpqExec(new.con, sql4) :
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "X1" of relation "origdata" does not exist
)

and part of my data frame for reference.
[image]

How can I get it to read the values from my data frame in to the table origdata? I need the columns to have those labels.

Comment: Column names of the DB table and your data.frame must match.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problems!

Comment: Reconsider saving data in wide format inside an enterprise RDBMS like Postgres. Number-suffixed columns even tables are not optimal database design. Use *one* column for day indicator and another for its value in long, normalized format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to import your data.frame into an existing database table, column names will have to match the SQL schema.